# Bumblebee on Ubuntu 16.04LTS with HWE stack

Tags: bumblebee, hardware-enablement-stack

I'm having issues installing bumblebee on 16.04.2 with HWE stack.

I can't satisfy the dependencies for bumblebee because the repository offered libs have the 'hwe' suffix. The GA versions are not compatible with HWE ones. So my very question is: Can I use bumblebee with proprietary nvidia blobs and HWE kernel and video stack or I should roll back to GA kernel and xorg, in order to use bumblebee with Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry. Question updated. I made research before posting here, but seems nobody has solution. It's not that i see error or something just go wrong with the installation or running bumblebee. It's just that i can't install It on 16.04.2 without rolling back to GA kernel and xorg(4.4 and 1.18 respectively). Perhaps someone should make fork of the original packages of bumblebee and it's tools to use the dependencies provided by Ubuntu, which has 'hwe' in their name. For example xorg, that is bundled in hwe stack is 'xorg-hwe' and bumblebee has no clue of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing server to 'Main server' from software sources settings fixed the issue.